# React is compiling VERY slow in Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am working on a React project on Visual Studio Code and it hasn't been working well since a week ago. It takes literally between 5 to 15 minutes to compile when I make changes. Not every time I make a changes, but it happens VERY often. Also, it takes like 15 minutes or more to start the development server.

I am using VSC version 1.54.1 and Node.js version 15.4.0.

I just can't work like that. Please somebody help me :(

Comment: It would require more information on how to reproduce your problem and what your current setup is

Comment: Do you have auto save on?

Comment: What information do you need? I dont have auto save on, I manually save with ctrl G